# Read loop that does not crash when file is recreated

Tags: python, file

I have a python script that needs to read bytes from a file and publish them in MQTT room. But the file could be recreated during the process (the python script have to be running 24/24).

I tried this code, but when the file is being recreated `os.path.isfile` always return false.

```
def mqttToTtyOnMessage(client, userdata, message):
        tty = openFile(filename, os.O_WRONLY)
        print("%s @ %s : Message from %s to %s\n" %
              (threadName, time.ctime(time.time()), message.topic, filename))
        try:
            os.write(tty, message.payload)
        except:
            print("%s @ %s : Unable to write message to file %s\n%s" %
                  (threadName, time.ctime(time.time()), filename, sys.exc_info()))
            while True:
                if os.path.isfile(filename):
                    print("%s @ %s : File exist, come back to main loop." % (threadName, time.ctime(time.time())))
                    subTty = openFile(filename, os.O_WRONLY)
                    os.write(subTty, message.payload)
                    break
                else:
                    print("%s @ %s : File still not exist, wait few seconds and check again." % (threadName, time.ctime(time.time())))
                    time.sleep(1)
        os.close(tty)
```

The function openFile looks like this :

```
def openFile(filename, permission):
    try:
        fd = os.open(filename, permission)
    except:
        print("%s @ %s : Unable to write message to file %s\n%s" %
            (threadName, time.ctime(time.time()), filename, sys.exc_info()))
    return (fd)
```

I hope you have ideas about an error in my code or another way to achieve this.
Thanks

**EDIT**: Solve this problem by changing the way I checked if the file exist :

```
def mqttToTtyOnMessage(client, userdata, message):
        try:
            tty = openFile(filename, os.O_WRONLY)
            os.write(tty, message.payload)
            print("%s @ %s : Message from %s to %s\n" %
              (threadName, time.ctime(time.time()), message.topic, filename))
        except OSError:
            print("%s @ %s : Unable to write message to file %s\n%s\n" %
                  (threadName, time.ctime(time.time()), filename, sys.exc_info()))
            while True:
                try:
                    subTty = openFile(filename, os.O_WRONLY)
                    os.write(subTty, message.payload)
                    break
                except:
                    print("%s @ %s : Can't open file for the moment, try again in 5s.\n%s\n" % ("mqttToTty", time.ctime(time.time()), sys.exc_info()))
                time.sleep(5)
        os.close(tty)
```

Comment: How often is the file recreated? I’m no expert on the subject, but surely there has to be an alternative to constantly reading/writing to the same file, right?

Comment: It depends but it can be few times per hours sometimes.